# Regex to separate two bracket closed items

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need to separate the following array:

```
[45645]
[5456]
[PB15] [DEC]
[PB16] []
```

with the regex I need to find the following of above's list:

```
[45645]   
[5456]  
[PB15]  
[PB16]
```

I had the following regex: `\[(.*[0-9]*)\]`

Unfortunately, it selects all the items within the square brackets.

Comment: How about: `\[[^\]]+\]`

Comment: So, there must be at least 1 digit inside `[...]`? Use [`\[[^][0-9]*[0-9][^][]*]`](https://regex101.com/r/jkpGIG/1)

Comment: @Toto: that matches [DEC] too.

Comment: `\[([^\]]*[0-9]+)\]` will select every item, that ends with a number.

Comment: do you really need an Regex for that? or just you want to do the task?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Didn't forget to up-vote. Tbh it barely escapes a down-vote with it's sketchy info...

Comment: @ClasG:  I would not be so picky here, the are posts much worse than this one. Everything but one detail is present in the question, but that can be deduced from the regex OP used.

Comment: \[@WiktorStribiżew That regex matches this complete comment. And that clears it up for you? [See this...](https://regex101.com/r/m51mGE/1)\]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\[(.*[0-9]*)\]` pattern matches `[`, then any 0+ chars as many as possible, then 0+ digits, and then `]`. This means that if you have multiple `[...]` on a line, they will be matched as one value and these `[...]` substrings do not really have to contain a digit anywhere.

If you want to match `[...]` strings that contain at least 1 digit *anywhere* in the square brackets, you may use

```
\[[^][0-9]*[0-9][^][]*]
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%5B%5E%5D%5B0-9%5D*%5B0-9%5D%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%5D&i=%5B45645%5D%0D%0A%5B5456%5D%0D%0A%5BPB15%5D%20%5BDEC%5D%0D%0A%5BPB16%5D%20%5B%5D)

**Details**:

- `\[` - a `[`
- `[^][0-9]*` - 0+ chars other than `[`, `]` and digits
- `[0-9]` - a single digit
- `[^][]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a single literal `]`.

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/OPqj9J):

```
var strs = new List<string> { "[45645]","[5456]","[PB15] [DEC]","[PB16] []"};
foreach (var str in strs) {
    var result = Regex.Matches(str, @"\[[^][0-9]*[0-9][^][]*]")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .ToList();
    foreach (var s in result)
        Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

**Alternatively**, you may use a simple `\[[^][]+]` regex to match `[...]` substrings (or `\[\w+]` if you only expect word chars in between `[` and `]`), but only grab those that contain at least 1 digit:

```
var result = Regex.Matches(str, @"\[[^][]+]") // Pattern may be \[\w+]
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .Where(m => m.Any(Char.IsDigit))   // Here, check if there is at least 1 digit
        .ToList();
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/hVVo6L)

Comment: Exactly what I meant! Thank you for this great advice!

Answer (score 2):

Not a very detailed question, but simply

```
 ^[^\s]*
```

should do it for you.

It matches anything up to a space (`\s` includes linefeed).

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4m91o9/1).

**Edit:**

As Gawil pointed out - could be shortened to `^\S*`. It means exactly the same thing, only it's shorter.

Comment: You can simplify this to `^\S*`

Comment: @Gawil Tru dat :)

Answer (score 0):

this pattern would capture in every case digits and the digits can be preceded by letters

```
\[\w*\d+\]
```

here is a [test](http://regexr.com/3g0bo)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your line endings are delimeted, but this should work in most cases:
^[(.*?)]

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is almost fine. You just need to anchor it at the beginning of the string and turn on the multi-line flag (m):
`^\[(.*[0-9]*)\]`
You can then simplify it :
`^\[.*?\d*\]`
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/iBPGNJ/2)